# gsutil cp failed with "Redirected more times than rediection_limit allows"

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am copying a tarball from a GKE container to GCS, and I am seeing the error "Redirected more times than rediection_limit allows" once a while.

The command I ran:

gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1 -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=250M -o GSUtil:parallel_process_count=18 cp XXX.tar.gz gs://path/to/object

And when I tried to resume the upload, I still got:

Redirected more times than rediection_limit allows.
CommandException: Some temporary components were not uploaded successfully. Please retry this upload.

What could be the cause of this issue and how can I solve/alleviate this issue?

gsutil will try to reuse some of the temporary files from last upload, could this be the reason why the upload can not be resumed?

Comment: Which version of the Cloud SDK are you using? I ask since I have seen this error on older versions

Comment: @rsalinas I don't have cloud sdk installed in my environment, my gsutil is installed as a stand-alone instance and the gsutil version is 4.47, which is pretty new.

Comment: I tried to use the same version as you, but got no error. Maybe you should try to upgrade to gsutil version 4.49 which is the latest and test if you still have the issue